# Connecting to my local WampServer from mobile?

Tags: php, android, wamp

I want to make an app for file transfer between mobile and a web server. I don't have web space yet and want to simulate that. The mobile part is ok. I have the PHP code too, Is there anyway I can run the PHP code to accept the file from the mobile by the PHP code and save the file to the WAMP server on my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I edited your question correctly. As I understand you want to connect to the server on your local computer from your mobile.

First you'll need to open the correct port on your PC and router. Then make sure WampServer is listening on that port and is not bound to an IP. For example instead of:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

You should have:

```
Listen 80
```

Or preferably a non-standard port rather than 80.

[See this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/395286/How-to-Access-WAMP-Server-in-LAN-or-WAN) for more details and other options to try. [This Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219062/cannot-access-wamp-server-on-local-network) question also has some other options.